# Can $.ajax() fire "success" before a request completes?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Let's say I'm `$.post()`-ing an AJAX request to a script that does the following:

```
echo "foo";
sleep(60);  // block request for some time
echo "bar";
```

Will the originating script fire the success function when it sees "foo", or when the ajax script is finally done after "bar" is echoed?

Comment: Can't you through a console.log after every function and see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be several `readystatechange` events while the response arrives, but the `readyState` only changes to 4 (Loaded) when the response is complete.

The jQuery library will call the `success` method when a `readystatechange` event happens and the `readyState` property is 4 (Loaded), and `status` property shows a successful status code (e.g. 200).

Comment: It seems to me that it executes `success` on each 2xx or 304 `status`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Ragnarokkr: Yes, you are right, there are several successful status codes.

Answer (score 1):

After the "bar". :) Or more precisely, when it receives HTTP header with status code 200. That means the script has finished execution.

Comment: Thanks - so let's say I wanted to return a response, but continue to do some work in that AJAX script - how could I handle that? Right now, my script is doing > 60 seconds worth of work, but has enough information after about 5 seconds to return a response. The originating script sees it as timing out, so even though the work is happening, the source script sees is as a timeout and in some cases even submits a duplicate ajax request.

Comment: @Matthew I'd suggest having your server send off an http request to a second script with a very small (0) timeout and catch the timeout error, then return to the ajax. your second script then continues to process.